# How to move focus from AutoCompletBox after selecting an item?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpftoolkit

In my application the user can add items to a `ListBox`. I wanted the user to be able to add a new item after selecting it from the `AutoCompleteBox`, by pressing the *Return Key* once more. I thought that setting the `IsDefault` property to `True` on the `Add` button would've been enough.

This is how the MainWindow code looks like:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" />

<Button Name="button1" Content="Add" IsDefault="True" Click="button1_Click" />

<my:AutoCompleteBox Name="autoCompleteBox1" 
                IsTextCompletionEnabled="True"
                PreviewKeyDown="autoCompleteBox1_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

As setting `IsDefault` didn't work because the `AutoCompleteBox` kept focus for itself,  I then tried to respond to the `KeyDown` event by checking if it was the *Return Key* that was pressed and try to set focus to the button.

But pressing the *Return Key* after selecting an item didn't fire the `KeyDown` event. So I finally subscribed to the `PreviewKeyDown` event and do this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<string> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listBox1.ItemsSource = myCollection;
        autoCompleteBox1.ItemsSource = new string[] { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5" };
    }

    private void autoCompleteBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            button1.Focus(); 
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (autoCompleteBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            myCollection.Add((string)autoCompleteBox1.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

But the button doesn't get the focus. How can I move focus away from the `AutoCompleteBox`?

Comment: Thanks @Blam that did the trick. How do I mark as answer?

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the KeyUp event.   KeyDown is too early in the cycle for changing focus.